# Cache not generating in ArcGIS Server v10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, cache

Apologies for any initial ambiguity in the question, I will attempt to make it a little clearer.

1. I have published a map service in ArcGIS Server.
2. In publishing, I have specified this map service to be a cached map service (I have set the levels, cache location, tile format, etc. AGS has no problem with any of these settings).
3. The service publishes successfully and AGS tells me that I can monitor the  creation of the cache through ArcCatalog.
4. When I go to ArcCatalog and check on the Cache Status it tells me that the cache generation is not in progress, (see screen grabs).
   [image][image]
5. The AGS log files are telling me:

> SEVERE Instance of the service 'System/CachingTools.GPServer' crashed.
>   2014-06-12T10:03:25 Server ‘Server Name’  8252  11464 1
>
> SEVERE Instance of service 'Service Name.MapServer' failed to process
>   a request. AutomationException: Unspecified error  2014-06-12T10:03:24
>   Server Name  8001  3161900 17
>
> SEVERE IPersistStream::Save failed.  2014-06-12T10:03:24 Service
>   Name.MapServer

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, have you figured out what the issue is?

Comment: Could you add more details on what exactly you are doing as well as insert a picture of the View Cache Status window?